# memory leak when using uploadify in IE

Tags: javascript, uploadify

I tried this in IE. Create a `uploadify control` (*flash version*) and destroy it, do these again and again. But it seems that the memory allcated doesn't release after method `destroy` called.

libs

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<link href="uploadify/uploadify.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="uploadify/jquery.uploadify.js"></script>
```

html

```
<button id="btnAdd">add</button>
<button id="btnRemoveLast">remove last</button>
<div id="container">
    <!--we will place uploadifies here-->
</div>
```

js

```
    <script>
        $(function () {            

            $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
                add();
            });
            $('#btnRemoveLast').click(function () {
                removeLast();
            });

            var count = 0;
            function removeLast() {
                if (count > 0) {
                    $('#uploadify' + --count).uploadify('destroy');
                }
            }
            function add() {
                var elem = $('<div id="uploadify' + count++ + '"></div>');
                $('#container').append(elem);
                elem.uploadify({
                    height: 30,
                    swf: '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                    width: 120
                });
            }
        });        
    </script>
```

Any answers will be appreciated, and thank you for pardoning my English:)

Comment: I'm sorry for that I didn't confirm this question enough before I post my question here. I notice that the `uploadify` control release the memory actually when its count reach a certain number.

Answer (score 1):

I'm  sorry for my late anwer. I  saw the question after my off work.I have found the the solution of the problem after i saw the uploadify's source code.
it seems worked at my IE11 .Pay attention to the queueid.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVZsQ.png)

However Why not try the `function CollectGarbage().Finally`,Please forget for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like another IE "fun".
If the problem is the the same for the problem that I know, nullify will be the answer.
In IE there is a bug with the GC, so you need to "release" yourself references and scope variables.

Try this:

```
 var upToDestroy =  $('#uploadify' + --count);
upToDestroy.uploadify('destroy');
upToDestroy = null;
```